# Tabs and Pager with custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, customization

I could manage to create a TabAdapter with pager (swiping tabs), which implements a ListFragment for each. Then I called my items through the strings. This works just fine.
But the ListView here implements plain text.
My question: how can implement a custom ListView with custom Rows (Text and image)?
Here is my code:

.MainActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    pager = new ViewPager(this);
    pager.setId(R.id.pager);
    setContentView(pager);

    final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    mTabsAdapter = new TabsAdapter(this, pager);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Grundlagen"), ListViewTabGrundlagen.class, null);
    mTabsAdapter.addTab(bar.newTab().setText("Anästhesie"), ListViewTabAnaesthesie.class, null);

}
```

ListViewTabGrundlagen

```
public class ListViewTabGrundlagen extends ListFragment {
    String[] list_items;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, container, false);
        list_items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.listGrundlagen);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list_items));

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


</ListView>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/pager" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any workaround?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Write a custom adapter for your listview according to the layout of the list item ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for the custom adapters, You can start by extending the BaseAdaper or ArrayAdapter and Overriding the proper methods in the classes.

Comment: But how can I extend the BaseAdapter while the activity already extends ListFragment?

Comment: You need to create a adapter class by extending the BaseAdapter Class and then you can set the object of the adapter in your list view class by calling the method setListAdapter().